# Is it illegal for a President or the Executive Branch to increase Congressional pay/benefits?

Tags: united-states, president

In a recent [Wall Street Journal](http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424127887324635904578644202946287548.html) article:

> The Affordable Care Act requires Members of Congress and their staffs to participate in its insurance exchanges, in order to gain first-hand experience with what they're about to impose on their constituents. [...]
>
> And now the White House is suspending the law to create a double standard. The Office of Personnel Management (OPM) that runs federal benefits will release regulatory details this week, but leaks to the press suggest that Congress will receive extra payments based on the FEHBP defined-contribution formula, which covers about 75% of the cost of the average insurance plan. For 2013, that's about $4,900 for individuals and $10,000 for families. [...]
>
> **This latest White House night at the improv is also illegal. OPM has no authority to pay for insurance plans that lack FEHBP contracts, nor does the Affordable Care Act permit either exchange contributions or a unilateral bump in congressional pay in return for less overall compensation. Those things require appropriations bills passed by Congress and signed by the President.**
>
> But the White House rejected a legislative fix because Republicans might insist on other changes, and Mr. Obama feared that Democrats would go along because they're looking out for number one. So the White House is once again rewriting the law unilaterally, **much as it did by suspending ObamaCare's employer mandate for a year.**

**Is it illegal for the President (or an office of the Executive Branch like the OPM) to write regulatory legislation that pays for insurance or increase pay to offset loss in benefits of Congress or Congressional staff?** (or does it require an appropriations bill from Congress)

**If it is illegal, what remediation is available to taxpayers?** (I would suspect that a citizen wouldn't have standing to bring this issue before the court, but I may be wrong)

Comment: The "question" tells you the answer.  Its not an actual question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First this is not legislation this is an executive order, which is an action the president can take to make sure the government is able to function.  In theory congress should come in and address the issue that the executive order was enacted for at their next meeting.  But the action most often taken is not to address the EO and allow it to stand.

Well this could be considered a violation of the [27th Amendment to the Constitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty-seventh_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution)

> The Twenty-seventh Amendment (Amendment XXVII) prohibits any law that
>   increases or decreases the salary of members of the Congress from
>   taking effect until the start of the next set of terms of office for
>   Representatives. It is the most recent amendment to the United States
>   Constitution. It was submitted to the states for ratification in 1789
>   and was adopted in 1992.

The interesting part here is what remedy there is.  In order to file a suit to challenge this you must have standing to bring the case.  In order to have [standing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_%28law%29) you must be able to show:

> 1. The party is directly subject to an adverse effect by the statute or
>      action in question, and the harm suffered will continue unless the
>      court grants relief in the form of damages or a finding that the law
>      either does not apply to the party or that the law is void or can be
>      nullified. This is called the "something to lose" doctrine, in which
>      the party has standing because they directly will be harmed by the
>      conditions for which they are asking the court for relief.
> 2. The party is not directly harmed by the conditions by which they are
>      petitioning the court for relief but asks for it because the harm
>      involved has some reasonable relation to their situation, and the
>      continued existence of the harm may affect others who might not be
>      able to ask a court for relief. In the United States, this is the
>      grounds for asking for a law to be struck down as violating the
>      First Amendment, because while the plaintiff might not be directly
>      affected, the law might so adversely affect others that one might
>      never know what was not done or created by those who fear they would
>      become subject to the law – the so-called "chilling effects"
>      doctrine.
> 3. The party is granted automatic standing by act of law. Under some
>      environmental laws in the United States, a party may sue someone
>      causing pollution to certain waterways without a federal permit,
>      even if the party suing is not harmed by the pollution being
>      generated. The law allows them to receive a portion of any fines
>      collected by the government from their violation of law. In some
>      U.S. states, a person who believes a book, film or other work of art
>      is obscene may sue in their own name to have the work banned
>      directly without having to ask a District Attorney to do so.

It will be very difficult to show that providing allowances to cover the cost of insurance from the exchanges has damaged you.  The justice department could bring suit since it it charged with defending the United States and the Constitution in court but being as they report to the President that is not something we can expect.  A states attorney general could file suit as well but they would have to show that this breach violates the states rights.

Comment: Hmm... " providing allowances to cover the cost of insurance" could be argued to damage me as a taxpayer. But IANAL so not sure how that legal theory would fare in front of the judge.

Comment: @DVK - how are you "directly subject to an adverse effect by the statute or action in question" - The money you pay in taxes stops being your money when you give it to the government.

Comment: Unless explicitly legislated to be revenue neutral, it increases either my tax burden, or the deficit. Both negatively affect me. Depending on whether the judge is a Demorcat or not, he may grasp this trivial economic truth or think that budget money grows on trees.

Comment: @DVK - If you can show that the increase in the deficit caused by this expense damaged you then yes you would have cause.  I am not saying you are not impacted.  But can you show the direct cause effect relationship and quantify the damages you personally have felt?  If so I beg you to sue.

Comment: Easy. Deficit=>inflation=>my savings are worth less. Or wait till next credit downgrade. Or till next tax hike.

Comment: @DVK - You would have to be able to show that the specific increase has led to inflation.  Being as the expense is probably going to be less than 1 million that is less that a millionth of the deficit... And while i agree it contributes to the problem by it self it is not a problem, thus doing you no signifigant harm so as to provide you cause.  If it was easy we would have stopped this along time ago.

Comment: Macro Econ 101. **Any increase** in money supply automatically increases inflation. The total inflation figure may be low due to other macro factors, but still higher than it would have been without the increase. Whether the harm is significant or not is a different question but that the harm is non-zero is a fact.

Comment: @DVK - Statistically for you the harm is probably going to be 0.  You have to be able to show that you were actually damaged.  If you damage is 0 then you were not actually damaged.  And there are many economic theories that disagree with the definition of inflation that you have presented.  But this is chat so please stop with the comments unless you can show **REAL** harm.

Comment: Just curios, are you sure about *submitted to the states for ratification in **1789***

Comment: @Ghanima - I wasnt there but that is what the history books have said for 2 centuries...

Comment: @DeplorableNumber9035768 ok thanks. I was just wondering about two hundred years of a ratification period.

Comment: @Ghanima Ohh yes forgot yeah it was one of those things where they didnt want it back then but got resurrected and ratified later.